# Android Pull to refresh keeps loading

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented the Android-PullToRefresh in the application. Everything works fine but the pull to refresh keeps on loading after data is loaded in the Listview.

```
    list = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.stored_location);
    alertLocationList = list.getRefreshableView();
    list.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_END);

    list.setOnRefreshListener((new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener< ListView>() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                      list.onRefreshComplete();
                    if (Integer.valueOf(totalCount)==Integer.valueOf(endcount)) {

                       //    list.onRefreshComplete();
                        Log.e(TAG,"----Loaded in listener---");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(TAG,"----calling next data---");
                        stored_List_Call();
                    }
                }
            }));
```

and below is my post execute method that I have used

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            switch (asynctaskEnum)
            {
                case storedLocationList:
                    try
                    {
                        if(result==null)
                        {
                            Log.e("result", "result is null");
                            return;
                        }
                        JSONObject header_Object=new JSONObject(result);
                        if(header_Object.getJSONObject("header").getString("status").equals("1")) {
                            response_Data(result); //this method parse the Json response and added it to the array list
                            if(userLocationsAdapter==null) {
                                Log.e(TAG,"list size--->"+storedUserLocationList.size());
                                userLocationsAdapter = new StoredLocationAdapter(storedUserLocationList, Activity.this);
                                alertLocationList.setAdapter(userLocationsAdapter);

                            }else
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "list size in else--->" + storedUserLocationList.size());
                                list.onRefreshComplete();
                                userLocationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                            }
                        else {

                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
```

Anyone tell me where I have missed the thing. I have spent a whole day to find this issue. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call

```
list.onRefreshComplete();
```

whenever your task is complete you need to call `onRefreshComplete()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        list.onRefreshComplete();
    }
```

Comment: I have already called the onRefreshComplete() in the Listener but it's not working.

Comment: I have already called the onReferesh complete before notifydatasetchange(), Please have a look into it  list.onRefreshComplete();
                                userLocationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: if you have done everything and still its not working than take a look at the issues of library you have used. Go to github and check it

Comment: @Rajsundar, answer is correct, first of all  you have to list.onRefreshComplete(); then do other stuff.

Comment: @HirenPatel Thank you, you are right, I haven't tried after dialog.dismiss()

Answer (score -1):

When your data loading / fetching has completed do not forget to call `swipRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`